# Is a query-inside-query to display categories like this possible?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```
function getForums($id) {
    $currentHost = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    try {
        global $db;
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $category_title = $row['category_title'];
            $category_id = $row['category_id'];
            echo '<div class="forum pleft">
                    <div class="forum-header">
                        <span class="header-text">'.$category_title.'</span>
                    </div>
                    <table>';
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE category_id='".$category_id."'";
            try {
                global $db;
                $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2); 
                $stmt2->execute();
                $result2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
                foreach($result2 as $row2) {
                    $forum_cat_id = $row2['category_id'];
                    $forum_id = $row2['forum_id'];
                    $forum_title = $row2['forum_title'];
                    $forum_topic_count = $row2['forum_topic_count'];
                    $forum_post_count = $row2['forum_post_count'];
                    $forum_last_topic_id = $row2['forum_last_topic_id'];
                    $forum_last_topic = $row2['forum_last_topic'];
                    $forum_last_date = $row2['forum_last_date'];
                    $forum_last_user = $row2['forum_last_user'];
                    $fixed_last_topic = substr($forum_last_topic,0,25).'...';
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td class="title"><a href="'.$currentHost.'/forums/view-forum/index.php?cid='.$forum_cat_id.'&fid='.$forum_id.'">'.$forum_title.'</a></td>
                            <td class="topics">'.$forum_topic_count.'</td>
                            <td class="posts">'.$forum_post_count.'</td>
                            <td class="lastpost"><a href="'.$currentHost.'/forums/view-thread/index.php?cid='.$id.'&fid='.$forum_id.'&tid='.forum_last_topic_id.'">'.$fixed_last_topic.'</a> by <a href="'.$currentHost.'/users/index.php?username='.$forum_last_user.'">'.$forum_last_user.'</a> at '.$forum_last_date.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>';
                }
            }
        } // Getting an error here!
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("error");
    }
}
```

I marked in the code where I'm getting an error, about 7 lines up.
I had another question but never got answered and basically I'm trying to make my forums so that all of the subcategories (forums) go into the category and don't make a whole new forum div each time.

Comment: Which is the error message? Almost sure this is a parenthesis problem.

Comment: Almost anytime you have nested queries, and the inner query uses the outer query's values for `where` filtering, you probably can/should re-write using a SINGLE `join`ed query.

Comment: Looks like you don't have ended TRY block with CATCH.

Comment: I just added a catch pdoexeception and still getting the same error. The error is something about T catch on line 44 (where I marked it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't written any catch for the second try. So the code will end with an error waiting for the catch.
change the code this way

```
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die("error");
}
} // Getting an error here!
```

Comment: I had added it but it seemed I didn't upload it. Sorry guys, thanks!